# Why does my ceiling light go out a few seconds after I turn it on?

Tags: electrical, light

Weird problem.  My ceiling light will not stay on in the morning.  When I flip the light switch it will go on for a few seconds and then go out.  However, in the afternoon, the light seems to work perfectly and will stay on.  I changed the wall socket and made sure all the wiring was connected in the light.  Wiggling the light socket switch has no effect. It is a ceiling light with fan.  No issues with the fan turning on or off at all.  Any ideas?

Comment: What type of lamp? It’s not a smart lamp by chance?

Comment: "Ceiling light with fan" and "changed the wall socket" do not line up. When you say "wall socket" do you mean the light and/or fan switch, or is this "ceiling fan with light" actually plugged into an electrical outlet, or did you do make some adjustment to the wiring in the box that the "ceiling light/fan" is attached to? Please [edit] your post to provide some more clarity.

Comment: Is there a fluorescent bulb?

Comment: I wonder if the centre contact has enough contact force. pry out with power off

Comment: I wonder if there is a photocell in the fixture...